# How to type a close brace `}` when clion doesn't understand your code and reformats it wrong?

Tags: c++, formatting, clion

I have some code that compiles fine but I type the closing brace `}` for the else, it moves all the code from the `else {` all the way to the left and throws away all indentation.

```
    if (some_condition) { 
        some_real_code();
    } else { 
        obj.some(stuff);
        obj(some,other(stuff));
```

and when I type the final `}` I get:

```
    if (some_condition) { 
        some_real_code();
    } else { 
obj.
some(stuff);
obj(
some, 
other(stuff));
}
```

The only way I've found to deal with this when it happens is to select a brace in my code, copy it to my clipboard, then do a right-click "paste simple" in clion, which doesn't do any reformatting.

Is there any better way?   For example, an a phone, if it autocorrects you and you delete the autocorrected word and retype the same word again, it won't re-autocorrect you because it figures you actually knew what you meant when you do it the second time.

Thank you.

edit: I'm not saying clion is bad or wrong for not understanding my code because in my real code I use language features that it doesn't claim to have support for.  I'm just looking for how to work around it's rather aggressive lack of support.

Comment: Do you really have `...blah...` in the code? Entering invalid syntax confuses many indenters.

Comment: Put it in a comment, like `/* ...blah... */`

Comment: @Barmar no, I'll update.  Sorry about that.  I haven't really figured out what causes the issue - the if body can be completely empty and it still happens.  I'm not particularly interested in working around the editor limitation in my code, though, as I assume the editor will eventually catch up with c++17 features - though probably just in time for '20.

Comment: :-) **12.5 k** rep., c++ score 308, c score 235 (Respect!) ...and you even didn't consider to change your IDE due to _it's rather aggressive lack of support_? How comes? There are other IDEs out there which are well supported and free as well. If you are such a fan of clion, may be, you should fix the formatters by yourself and contribute...

Comment: On the other hand... I long sticked to `xemacs` until I had to change to cygwin64 (after a certain update, the 32 bit version was broken on my PC) where `xemacs` in turn is broken. But, `xemacs` has features (e.g. it can replace considering upper CASE and camel Case appropriately which is _very_ useful for refactoring) which I never found anywhere else. I still miss it... (sometimes). I still write the special first-line comments into my `.h` files to tell `xemacs` that they are C++ hoping that `xemacs` will be fixed one day. So, there might be reasons for you also...

Comment: @Scheff it's very infrequent so I deal with it.   I often tell people CLion is a terrible IDE, but it's way ahead of anything else :)  With the exception of things like this (which again, aren't frequent), it matches my workflow extremely well.

Comment: @Scheff: Everything's a trade-off innit. No reason not to try to improve the things we've traded-off against though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, switch off "Reformat block on typing '}'":

[image: Reformat block on typing '}']

Seems that you would be interested in [for-IDE-stub implementation](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/02/clion-2017-1-eap-debugger-fixes-ide-macros-and-new-cmake/) in guarded block (Per-ide variable: in CLion it’s **CLION_IDE** , in AppCode – **APPCODE_IDE** , in Android Studio – **STUDIO_IDE**)
[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you.  I don't know if I'll do this or not, as I use that functionality on a regular basis.   Maybe if I can find a way to toggle it quickly via a keybinding or something.

Answer (score 1):

I would not turn autoformatting off, because in the majority of cases it is useful. But when this undesired autoformatting happens, I just do the following  workaround:

1. Cancel the autoformatting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>). The curly bracket is cancelled too.
2. Instead of typing bare `}`, I type it commented: `//}`.
3. Then just uncomment this line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or remove the slashes).

Profit! :)